# Varios metodos a la vez

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy realizando un formulario en `Javascript` el cual cada vez que el usuario actualice cualquiera de los `inputs`, me gustaria saber como poder enviar por consola lo que acaba de actualizar sin necesidad de tener que separar el codigo en 3 eventos `change` diferentes.

```js
$("#lista").change(function(){
    var opcion = $("#lista").val();
    var primeraFecha = $("#primeraFecha").val();
    var segundaFecha = $("#segundaFecha").val();

    var dia = parseInt(primeraFecha.substr(8,2));
    var mes = parseInt(primeraFecha.substr(5,2));
    var year = parseInt(primeraFecha.substr(0,4));

    console.log("Opcion: ", opcion);
    console.log("Primera Fecha: ", primeraFecha);
    console.log("Segunda Fecha: ", segundaFecha);
    console.log("Dia: ", dia);
    console.log("Mes: ", mes);
    console.log("Año: ", year);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Prueba con ajax</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

     <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
            <h4>Jquery</h4>
        </div>
            
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="primeraFecha">1era Fecha <span></span></label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="primeraFecha" id="primeraFecha">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="segundaFecha">2da Fecha <span></span></label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="segundaFecha" id="segundaFecha">
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lista">Lista</label>
                        <select class="custom-select" id="lista" name="lista">
                            <option selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                            <option value="1">Gestión Administrativa</option>
                            <option value="2">Rentabilidad</option>
                            <option value="3">Calidad de Activo</option>
                            <option value="4">Liquidez</option>
                            <option value="5">Cobertura</option>
                            <option value="6">Intermediación</option>
                            <option value="7">Apalancamiento</option>
                            <option value="8">Endeudamiento</option>
                            <option value="9">Solvencia</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="indicadores.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que podrías agregar el listener no por ID sino por tipo de elemento: $("select").on("change", function(e){//tucodigo}) dónde "e" trae la información propia del evento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una posibilidad es asignar una clase a todos los elementos en los que quieres detectar el cambio, ejémplo.

```js
$(".campo").change(function(){ //<-- detectamos el change de todo lo que tenga .campo
    var opcion = $("#lista").val();
    var primeraFecha = $("#primeraFecha").val();
    var segundaFecha = $("#segundaFecha").val();

    var dia = parseInt(primeraFecha.substr(8,2));
    var mes = parseInt(primeraFecha.substr(5,2));
    var year = parseInt(primeraFecha.substr(0,4));

    console.log("Opcion: ", opcion);
    console.log("Primera Fecha: ", primeraFecha);
    console.log("Segunda Fecha: ", segundaFecha);
    console.log("Dia: ", dia);
    console.log("Mes: ", mes);
    console.log("Año: ", year);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Prueba con ajax</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

     <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
            <h4>Jquery</h4>
        </div>
            
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="primeraFecha">1era Fecha <span></span></label>
                        <input type="date" class="campo form-control" name="primeraFecha" id="primeraFecha">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="segundaFecha">2da Fecha <span></span></label>
                        <input type="date" class="campo form-control" name="segundaFecha" id="segundaFecha">
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lista">Lista</label>
                        <select class="campo custom-select" id="lista" name="lista">
                            <option selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                            <option value="1">Gestión Administrativa</option>
                            <option value="2">Rentabilidad</option>
                            <option value="3">Calidad de Activo</option>
                            <option value="4">Liquidez</option>
                            <option value="5">Cobertura</option>
                            <option value="6">Intermediación</option>
                            <option value="7">Apalancamiento</option>
                            <option value="8">Endeudamiento</option>
                            <option value="9">Solvencia</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="indicadores.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```